# Как изменить цвет выпадающего меню?

Tags: android, menu

Выпадающее меню отображается с темным фоном. Пробовал менять фон в стилях, но меню просто окрашивается в белый цвет и не видно букв. Как сделать чтобы был светлый фон и темные буквы, чтобы не отличалось от общей темы приложения?

**Меню**

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
tools:context=".view.MainActivity">
<item
    android:id="@+id/action_menu"
    android:title="@string/menu_title_about"
    app:showAsAction="collapseActionView" />
<item
    android:id="@+id/share_menu"
    android:title="@string/share_the_app"
    app:showAsAction="collapseActionView" />
<item
    android:id="@+id/rate_menu"
    android:title="@string/rate_this_app"
    app:showAsAction="collapseActionView" />

<item
    android:id="@+id/action_search"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_search"
    android:title="@string/search"
    app:showAsAction="ifRoom" />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

в xml разметке вашего toolbar настройте:

```
android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
app:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark"
app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Toolbar"
```

если вы используете ActionBar наследуйте тему вашего приложения от Light тем